# How can I create a fade effect between scenes in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, graphic-effects

I have implemented a screen fade with Scene2D.  It currently fades fades out of one screen to black, then then from that black into the next screen.  It would be really awesome if I could fade straight from the first screen to the new screen, without the black state between.  Is this possible?

I tried using the parallel method but it just did everything all at once.  I want it to kind of morph through the screens.

Answer (score 3):

While rendering the two scenes, the first one over the target one, you can just make a fade effect on opacity on the first one.

Here is what i suggest :

1. Create a "TransitionScene" wrapper that take the two scene as parameters and have them rendered and updated (override act and render)
2. Apply a color action to have the first scene opacity move from 1 to 0
3. When this action is finished, set your current game scene to the second one.

I have some code [here](https://github.com/Khopa/Khopa_LibGDX_Codebase/tree/master/core/src/com/khopa/core/actions/transitions) that might help you get the idea, though it's probably not the best example :